# TableLayout in Android using Imageview

Tags: android, image, android-layout, android-studio, android-tablelayout

How to add `Image` view inside the `table row` (Using `XML` only) `tag` where I cannot find the images `Visibled` ?

My following code of XML is:

```
<TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent">
  <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/golis" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
  </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

I need help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add ImageView insid table row (Using XML), as Below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="#FFF">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/YOUR_IMAGE" /> //change imagesize as per devices
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```